# I'm building a javascript app, I need a lightweight php script to interact with a database and javascript using json

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, database-connection

My app is a very complex game that uses json objects to store its execution state (aka save games). I'm looking for a nice database script that can talk json and interact with javascript via ajax.

Comment: are you looking for one thats already made? or are you asking if php can do this? i dont know what youre asking

Comment: do you want to store a json object into the database?  if so, you should be fine just storing it as a string

Comment: @Galen I'm looking for an already established solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean something like http://www.persvr.org/ ?

Comment: yea pretty much, The only problem is that I am using php not javascript on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how familiar you are with php, but you can send JSON objects to a php with ajax and then use json_decode() to turn the JSON object into an associative array, then when you want to pass a JSON object back, you have your use json_encode() on your associative array and it will turn it into a JSON object that gets returned to javascript.
As far as having a database script ready made, you'll have to be more specific with what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm fairly skilled with php, I'm just wondering if this kind of things already exists.